# Use Web API Web Client to pass array for GET method

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an integer array as a criteria for a GET Web API from my WP8 application using Web Client. I have tried both Download and Upload string but was unable to pass the criteria through to the API

The following is my current code

**Web API Controller method**

```
public IQueryable<Items> GetItemByColour([FromUri] int[] Colour)
{
var query = from a in db.Items
        where Colour.Contains(a.ItemsColour)
        select a;

return query;}
```

**WP8 Application**

```
void btnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            int[] arr = new int[3];
            arr[0] = 1;
            arr[1] = 2;
            arr[2] = 3;

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://ip:Port/api/Items/?Colour="+arr);
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Items> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(e.Result);
            foreach (Item em in items)
            {
                int phoneID = em.ItemID;
                string phoneName = em.ItemName;
                lstPhones.Items.Add(phoneId + " " + phoneName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET WebApi will automatically convert parameters with the same name to arrays if that's how you define your service action. So, if your URL is //ip:port/api/Items/?Colour=1&Colour=2 the `Colour` array will be equal to `int[2] { 1, 2 }` on the server side.

It should work fine if you do it like this:

```
 int[] arr = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
 System.Text.StringBuilder colourParams = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
 {
     colourParams.Append("Colour=").Append(arr[i]);
     if (i != arr.Length - 1)
     {
         colourParams.Append("&");
     }
 }

 Uri uri = new Uri("http://ip:port/api/Items/?" + colourParams.ToString());
```